# How to start rebuild in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins

Is there a way in Jenkins to rebuild the old build jobs ? For instance I want to build job with the build number #712 but when I click the job link's I don't see any build option to restart the build.

Answer (score 15):

Jenkins provide a plugin called **"Rebuild plugin"** after installing this [**plugin**](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Rebuild+Plugin) user allows to rebuild a parametrized build without entering the parameters again.It will also allow the user to edit the parameters before rebuilding.

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: At the time of *this* comment, [the *Rebuild Plugin* has not been able to consider the git revision of that to-be-rebuild build number](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-29765), but always uses the current HEAD revision -- i.e., the *Rebuild Plugin* doesn't make sense if the project build outcome depends on the state of your git repository.

Comment: Does anyone know if a build triggered from a GitLab merge request can be rebuilt using the MR source branch? The plugin does not seem to know for what branch it was invoked, and proposes `master` instead.

Comment: @Abdull , it question actual for me now, your have answer?

Answer (score 3):

In my (frustrating) experience, the "Build Now" or "Restart" or "Replay" buttons are not there because you didn't login Jenkins!

Answer (score 1):

today, they name it "Restart From Stage"